# Linq to Entities Join to Show Name in Lookup Table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF Code First (hybrid, database generation disabled) and I have two models/tables. I'm try to select and return all values in T1 and one field in a reference/lookup table so I can perform filtering on the list without requerying the database. I need to have the value of ItemName available so I can do comparisons.

If I were using SQL I'd just do something like this:

```
SELECT s.*, im.ItemName 
FROM Specs s 
    INNER JOIN ItemMake im ON s.ItemMakeID = im.ID
```

My classes look something like this:

```
public class Spec {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int ItemMakeID {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ItemMakeID")]
    public ItemMake itemMake {get; set;}
}
public class ItemMake {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
}
```

Currently my Linq to EF query looks like this. It doesn't work. I can't get at the ItemName property like I need to.

```
var specs = (from s in db.Specs 
    join im in db.ItemMakes on s.ItemMakeID equals im.ID 
    orderby s.modelNo select s).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're selecting just `s` in `select` clause. Use anonymous type declaration to get `ItemName` too:

```
var specs = (from s in db.Specs 
    join im in db.ItemMakes on s.ItemMakeID equals im.ID 
    orderby s.modelNo select new { s, im.ItemName }).ToList();
```

Comment: It works. Now I get the fun of changing the anonymous type to a valid type so I can bind to it in WPF.